# A bit of tiling

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, optimization

I just finished writing a small script to combine a lot of png pictures into
a bigger one for CSS Sprite.

So basically, I have a list of dimensions   [(w1,h2), ..., (wn,hn)]
and I need to put them into a frame with dimension (W,H) with WH as
small as possible. (Of course they cannot overlap)

The heuristic I used is obviously not optimal. I was wondering
if you had any ideas on the subject? 
Do you think some smarter constraint, like grouping images with
similar histograms would make the png smaller?

Comment: I think this problem may be NP-Complete.

Comment: It certainly seems close enough to the Knapsack problem and the Bin packing problem that it should be NP-Complete. However, the last sentence makes me wonder if this is really about arranging the individual images, rather than minimizing the file size of the collage.

Comment: Good question. My problem was more about minimizing the file size of the collage... but that sounded a bit hairy for a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious from how you pose the question whether it is the dimensions of the picture, or the size of the PNG file, which you want to optimize, as picture histograms do not affect their dimensions (width and height).

However, finding minimal K so that, say, max(W, H) < K, so that all your pictures can be fit into a rectangular area W wide and H tall is an NP-complete problem, which means that it is difficult to solve well in general. See for example [here](http://www-rcf.usc.edu/~skoenig/icaps/icaps04/icapspapers/ICAPS04KorfR.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

About making the resulting png smaller:

Be sure to use best compression level (level 9) and if possible, use [PNGOUT](http://www.advsys.net/ken/utils.htm) to compress the PNG even better (there's a [PNGOUT plugin](http://www.irfanview.net/plugins.htm) for [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.net/), too).

Grouping images with similar histograms could be good, note that PNG uses zLib which uses a sliding window, so it work best if you group the images horizontal.

EDIT: Same for free space. It should be better to have free space at the top or the bottom of the image than at the left or right. The color of the free space shouldn't really matter, some color or black or white should be fine.

By the way, the size of the zLib sliding window is 32K, so it's not that good for detecting image duplicates if images are big. You'd better process the images yourself with an own algorithm in this case and use some duplicate removal or delta filter.

Answer (score 1):

How does the output from your script compare to the output from [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)?

Comment: WOW! I didn't know about the montage option! I'll try that too!